# Filter string - apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using Apache Pig to filter dataset that contain several fields (string and int). The Filter command works fine with fields have integer only. Every time trying to filter string it faild.

#

Example of using Filter with int

```
Dat = FILTER datas BY (id == 123);
```

Above example works fine.

#

Example of using Filter with string

```
Dt = FILTER datase BY (User == "Sam");
```

Above example never works.

Can any one help on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what your data looks like. Also, you put datse instead of datas, and aliases are case sensitive

Make sure there are not extra whitespace in your chararray fields

Pig uses single quotes for chararray types

Answer (score 0):

I think it was clear for expert Apache Hadoop users.......anyway Thanks I solve it